# How to change Win32_NetworkAdapter NetConnectionID property using WMI

Tags: c++, windows, networking, wmi

I am writing a VC++ program which needs to change Network Connection name (eg. "Local Connection").

The Windows's IPHELPER provides API to get network connection, but it doesn't provide write method.
And I know I can use "netsh" to change this network connection name, yes, in English Windows, this method works properly, but in Japanese or Chinese Windows this method can't work properly.

After read some documents in MSDN, I found WMI Win32_NetworkAdapter class has a property "NetConnectionID". This property contains the adapter's network connection name, and its read/write perperty.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx

```
NetConnectionID 
Data type: string 
Access type: Read/write
```

So, I wrote a WMI code to change this property value.

```
int RasWmiAdapterSetInfo(void *pWmiAdapterCfg)
{
    if(pWmiAdapterCfg)
    {
        int retVal = -1;
        HRESULT hres;
        VARIANT varWrite;
        RAS_WMI_W32_ADAPTER_PTR *pRasWmiAdapterCfg = (RAS_WMI_W32_ADAPTER_PTR*)pWmiAdapterCfg;

        VariantInit(&varWrite);
        V_VT(&varWrite) = VT_BSTR;
        V_BSTR(&varWrite) = SysAllocString(L"My New Connection 1");
        hres = pRasWmiAdapterCfg->pclsObj->Put(L"NetConnectionID", 0, &varWrite, 0);
        if(FAILED(hres))
        {
            printf("RasWmiAdapterSetInfo Failed HR=%08x\n", hres);
            goto CLEARUP;
        }
        retVal = 0;
CLEARUP:

        VariantClear(&varWrite);
        return retVal;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The return value hres was OK, but this property value was not changed.

```
IWbemLocator         *pLoc;
IWbemServices        *pSvc;
IEnumWbemClassObject *pEnumerator; 
 ...
 ... (ignore some code to init pLoc, pSvc, pEnumerator)
 ...
IWbemClassObject *pclsObj;
IWbemClassObject *pClass;
pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);
pSvc->GetObject( bstr_t(adapterClsName), 0, NULL, &pClass, NULL );
```

Is anyone can tell me why the pclsObj->Put method did not take effect?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, `IWbemClassObject::Put()` only updates a class instance's property value in memory. To commit changes to WMI repository, you need to call `IWbemServices::PutInstance()` to update entire class instance.

So adding something like this to your code should get it to work:

```
IWbemCallResult* callResult = nullptr;
HRESULT hr = wbemSvc_->PutInstance(pClass, WBEM_FLAG_UPDATE_ONLY,
    nullptr, &callResult);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && callResult)
    callResult->Release();
```

Hope that helps!